# How to authenticate user without login

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, forms-authentication

Is it possible to authenticate user under the standard **ASP .NET MVC4** project using only  **UserId** so we can skip the code below?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok here is the solution

```
var userId = "123";

using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
{
   UserProfile userProfile = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userProfile.UserName, false);
}
```

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: @mikalai As you can see I asked if it is possible to use `UserId` and dont use WebSecurity.Login because the password is unknown. So we can get directly user entity which has Username ` FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` and authenticate user so he like logged in. It makes sense when we have mapped user record for the 2 sub-domains and want to implement autologin user for sub-domain website if the user is already logged into the other sub-domain website. You can read more about it here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic **

Comment: @mikalai How to share the authentication cookie across multiple domains?** . So we can include i.e. `UserId` and authenticate user for the second sub-domain website.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me next request i lose this info and i have the
websecurity.currentusername keeps returning the previous user username